# Is there a way to automatically install all package requirements for an R file?

Tags: r, installation, package, rscript

I have an R file, but it has packages which are not installed on my R installation. Is there a utility which determines these dependencies from the R file and installs all of them? I don't want to manually install them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The pacman package offers an efficient way to install / load packages in a single line.
You can refer to this [article](https://statsandr.com/blog/an-efficient-way-to-install-and-load-r-packages/).
I'm not aware of a way that installs packages completely automatically, as there might be namespace overlap between functions, etc...

Comment: Useful; but this does not answer the question. I guess there is nothing.